# minikube addons ingress - Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.k8s.io/v2/"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I just started minikube with `minikube start` and ran the following command to enable ingress in my local cluster.

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

After running the above command relevant pod in the `ingress-nginx` namespace does not have a running status.

After describing pod `ingress-nginx-admission-create-xxxxx` I can see this error:

```
vents:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  78s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-admission-create-mf9gd to minikube
  Warning  Failed     29s                kubelet            Failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20230407@sha256:543c40fd093964bc9ab509d3e791f9989963021f1e9e4c9c7b6700b02bfb227b": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.k8s.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on 192.168.65.2:53: server misbehaving
  Warning  Failed     29s                kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    29s                kubelet            Back-off pulling image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20230407@sha256:543c40fd093964bc9ab509d3e791f9989963021f1e9e4c9c7b6700b02bfb227b"
```

**Note:** I tried pulling that image from another registry, changing the tag, and moving it manually to minikube. But, I'll see the same error. It seems to want to send a request and ensure the `sha256`.

If I change the default minikube registry to another one can that help? If true, how?

If you have any possible ideas please feel free and tell me in the comment, and I'll check it.